# ckan apikey dataset using additional methods?

Tags: python, api, dataset, ckan

I have been challenged to make use of python ckan dataset.
Please help me
I want the image guide ... or even answer thanks...

```
  >>> import requests
  >>> import json
  >>> url='http://demo.ckan.org/api/action/resource_create'
  >>> auth_key='my key'
  >>> datastore_structure = {
                     'resource_id' : 'hojintop' ,
                     'fields' : [ { "id" : "a" }, { "id" : "b" } ],
                     "records" : [ { "a" : 1 , "b" : "xyz" }, { "a" : 2 , "b" : "zzz" } ]}
  >>> headers = { 'content-type' : 'application/json' , 'Authorization' : auth_key }
  >>> r = requests . post ( url + 'datastore_create' , data = json . dumps ( datastore_structure ), headers = headers )
```

but 
mypython have no effect 
demockan site have no effect ....
OMG........OTL......PLZ HELP ME...EASY GUIDE PLZ ..THANKYOU!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're trying to do.  For starters, it looks like you're trying to create a resource and a datastore in one transaction, which you can't do.  If you are trying to create a resource, you have to associate it with an existing package by specifying the package_id.  [Here's the API documentation](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/api/index.html#ckan.logic.action.create.resource_create).